# Would this question be on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm very curious about the differences, if any, between a [soundbar](http://static.trustedreviews.com/94/000027371/742c_orh616w616/Philips-Soundbar-Speaker-HTL5120-image-2-KI.jpg) and a standard stereo speaker.

Would a question like that be on-topic here?

Comment: +1 for asking and worrying about it. I think that it might be possible to formulate a question about it so that it is ontopic; maybe (since I assume that you know how a normal speaker works) it goes more into the direction of how such a thing works, and then you derive the differences yourself? I don't really know, speakers for me are electronically just an inductance and the rest is non electronic engineering ;)

Comment: @PlasmaHH Thanks, I'm just really interested to know if a bar can somehow produce superior sound quality to a speaker. I don't really understand how it could.

Comment: some people will claim it does when painted black, and doesnt when painted red, but well, the best is probably to understand *how* it works, then judge yourself if this is better for your very own definition of better.

Comment: Advantages and disadvantages[edit]
Soundbars are relatively small and can be easily positioned under a display, are easy to set up, and are usually less expensive than other stereo sound systems. However, due to their smaller size and lack of flexibility in positioning, soundbars do not fill a room with sound as well as separate speaker stereo systems.[3]